# hide perspectives

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created one perspective in eclipse workbench, not in eclipse rcp.Is it possible to hide other perspectives like java,debug? I just want to show only my perspective in my application.That should be the default one.Or I dont need to show any perspectives but my perspective which I created should be the default one. How do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [activities](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_activities.html).

I also wrote a blog entry on this some years back: [Using activities for user management](http://tonnymadsen.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-activities-for-user-management.html).

**UPDATED** the link

Answer (score 0):

You can close wanted perspective like below:

```
IPerspectiveDescriptor[] openPerspectives = page.getOpenPerspectives();
for (IPerspectiveDescriptor openPerspective : openPerspectives) {
//add your own perspective name
  if (openPerspective.getLabel().equals("<perspectiveLabel>")) {
    page.closePerspective(openPerspective, false, false);
  }
}
```